# Is it wrong to place inline functions in C headers?

Tags: c, inline, c-header

I am building a C project for several compilers, some of which are legacy compilers which don't seem to have link time inlining support, so it seemed logical to place `static inline` functions directly in headers and actually have each translation unit have its own copy.

Also, I need to ensure certain functions are inlined so that there are no calls to other functions (i.e. changes to CPU registers) when called inside certain low-level interrupt handlers, so it's not simply about letting the compiler choose if it will affect performance.

However, a colleague of mine told me this is an unusual thing to do and I should avoid it. At this point in project I can probably still rearrange everything, so I would just like to confirm if there are some issues we might face in the long run if we decide to use header inlines?

Comment: *"legacy compilers"* - But they do support the C99 inline specifier?

Comment: @StoryTeller: yes, this particular compiler has `_inline`, but doesn't support pretty much anything from C99 (e.g. variables need to be declared first thing in a scope block).

Comment: Well, then I don't think it's possible to predict all issues you may face. If the compiler supports `_inline` as opposed to the standard `inline`, you should study the documentation of that compiler specific specifier *very carefully*.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Thanks for the pro tip, I actually went and read the pretty short remark in the manual and it states exactly that: "With the `_inline` keyword, a C function can be defined to be inlined by
the compiler. An inline function must be defined *in the same source file
before it is ’called’*. When an inline function has to be called in several
source files, each file must include the definition of the inline function.
*This is typically solved by defining the inline function in a header file*." Perhaps you can add an answer with some info anyway?

Comment: I would if I had anything meaningful to say :) This compiler specific specifier seems to be about forced inlinling, as opposed to C99's ODR geared `inline`. So `static _inline` may be okay. You'd have to examine the generated object files.

Comment: It's the only place to have them ...

Comment: If you need to force inlining, it might be better to use the `#define foo(bar) do { int internal_##bar = bar; ... } while(0)` construct, i.e. perform the inlining within the preprocessor. Cause compilers are allowed to entirely ignore `inline` as they please.

Comment: @cmaster: I take your point but I would argue that if you are trusting your compiler with generating specific low-level code without touching specific reserved registers, then you _need_ a detailed understanding and guarantees of the compiler implementation specifics in any event. In which case trusting to inlining behavior is little different from other code generation specifics being relied upon, and there is also little point to avoiding extensions forcing the required behavior. Note that some embedded compilers optimize for size by splitting off common code into sub-functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From n1570 (latest public C11 draft), §6.7.4:

> 6. A function declared with an `inline` function specifier is an *inline function*. Making a
>      function an inline function suggests that calls to the function be as fast as possible. The extent to which such suggestions are effective is implementation-defined.

The next section goes into details about linkage, but this passage above is basically all the C standard has to say about `inline`. Note how this gives the implementation every freedom, including to completely ignore `inline`.

Therefore, with just standard C, you could end up with multiple instances (one per translation unit) of a function that is called in the normal way. This is normally not what you want, as it combines two disadvantages (duplicated code **and** the overhead of a function call). So I'd argue the standard C `inline` is only ever useful for functions private to a single translation unit. Even then, you could assume a good optimizing compiler will automatically pick candidates for inlining, without an explicit `inline`.

If on the other hand your compiler provides a way to actually *force* inlining of a function (which according to your comments, the `_inline` specifier does for your compiler), having these functions in a header is safe. But be aware it is in no way portable.

As [commented by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45208072/is-it-wrong-to-place-inline-functions-in-c-headers/45208626#comment77383602_45208072) [cmaster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2445184/cmaster), you can achieve kind of "*manual inlining*" with *function-like macros* instead for a portable solution.

Comment: C99 _does_ provide a mechanism for avoiding duplicated non-inlined instances through the `extern inline` construct, manually instantiating the fallback function definition into a single compilation unit. In which case plain `inline` is also to be used in place of `static inline` for the declaration. Actually, even without inlining allowing the compiler to _see_ the function definition can be a significant performance win, permitting reasoning about the function such as hoisting a constant result out of a loop or the like.

Answer (score 3):

According to the comments on the question, defining `static _inline` functions in header files is the way to go *for this specific compiler*, the quotation from the compiler doc is clear about that.

The problem you could later face is that it is a specific extension for a specific compiler, distinct from the *standard* `inline` specifier. As said by Felix, the standard allows the implementation to choose how it implements inlining, and in particular, ignoring the specifier would still be conformant:

> Making a function an inline function suggests that calls to the function be as
>   fast as possible. **The extent to which such suggestions are effective is
>   implementation-defined**.

That being said, the semantics seems to the the same (from draft 1256 for C99 or draft 1570 for C11):

> 6.7.4 Function specifiers
> ...
>   Any function with internal linkage can be an inline function. For a function with external
>   linkage, the following restrictions apply: If a function is declared with an inline
>   function specifier, then it shall also be defined in the same translation unit. If all of the
>   file scope declarations for a function in a translation unit include the inline function
>   specifier without extern, then the definition in that translation unit is an inline
>   definition. An inline definition does not provide an external definition for the function,
>   and does not forbid an external definition in another translation unit. An inline definition
>   provides an alternative to an external definition, which a translator may use to implement
>   any call to the function in the same translation unit. It is unspecified whether a call to the
>   function uses the inline definition or the external definition

So as common implementations do honour the `inline` specifier, my opinion is that the risk in portability is limited